# Symfony2 FormType + Doctrine inheritance

Tags: php, forms, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I'm using doctrine class table inheritance, and i don't know how to use it with the Form component of symfony2.

The schema is as follow :

Parent -- ManyToMany bidirectional-- Child
ChildBoy inherit from Child
ChildGirl inherit from Child

Now i have a FormType for my Parent (App\Bundle\ParentFormType), and i would like something like this :

```
$builder
        ->add('Child', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ChildType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
        ))
```

The problem is that Child has no property ChildBoy and ChildGirl, and i can't link them (to bind their property with the request) with a Parent in a formtype.

I looked in the doc, but i can't find anything about such case. I know i could handle it in my controller with custom logic, but i would like to know if there is a proper way to do it.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: So if i understand correctly you are trying to create a form to create a family? Where a ChildBoy or a ChildGirl could be added?

Comment: Yes this is exactly the point.

Comment: How was this implemented ? interesting question